# how to yield lua script in C Function

Tags: lua, yield, mscapi

it works when lua call a C API
if a C function call lua function, and the lua function call C API,  longjmp error

lua_yieldk, lua_callk, and lua_pcallk
how does it work?

my c code:

```
int trace(lua_State *L)
{
    const char *str = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    printf("%d:%s\n", GetTickCount(), str);
    return 1;
 }

int pause(lua_State *L)
{
    printf("pause");
    return lua_yield(L, 0);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate(); 
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_pushcfunction( L, pause );
    lua_setglobal( L, "pause" );
    lua_pushcfunction( L, trace );
    lua_setglobal( L, "trace" );
    if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua"))
       error(L, "cannot run script %s\n", lua_tostring(L,-1));
    lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
        lua_getglobal(L, "t");
    lua_pcallk(L, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
    lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
    lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
    lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
    lua_close(L);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

lua code

```
function t()
pause(2)
pause(2)
pause(2)
pause(2)
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call lua_resume on a thread returned by `lua_newthread`, not `lua_newstate`.

So in your code you would either have to change the first `lua_resume` to `lua_(p)call`:

```
if (luaL_loadfile(L, "test.lua"))
   error(L, "cannot run script %s\n", lua_tostring(L,-1));
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
```

or swap `luaL_loadfile` for `luaL_dofile`:

```
if (luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua"))
   error(L, "cannot run script %s\n", lua_tostring(L,-1));
//lua_resume(L, NULL, 0); Not necessary anymore
```

I'm not relating to the efficiency of setting the global `t` here.

Now to the main point of the question:

- First, each call to `lua_callk`, `lua_pcallk` or `lua_yieldk` needs to receive a continuation function as an argument. In your case it's 0. Actually, `lua_yieldk` can take 0 as continuation function, but then control is passed back to Lua script, where the call to the C function occured.
- Next, any call to those functions must be made within a coroutine thread, not the main thread.
- And lastly, you cannot yield across C call boundary. That is, when you call `lua_pcallk` and the chunk that pcallk is calling yields, the continuation function is executed. However, you cannot have `lua_pcallk` call a Lua function that in turn calls a C function that yields (`pause` in your example). That's forbidden.

**An example of `lua_pcallk`:**

```
int cont(lua_State *L)
{
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int pcallktest(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_loadstring(L, "yield()");
    int test = lua_pcallk(L, 0, 0, 0, 0, cont);
    return 0;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_State *T = lua_newthread(L);

    luaL_loadfile(T, "Test.lua");
    lua_pushcfunction(T, pcallktest);
    lua_resume(T, NULL, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Lua code:

```
local pcallktest = ...
pcallktest()
```

Now this piece of code starts a new coroutine from file "Test.lua". The Lua code calls C function `pcallktest`, which in turn calls `lua_pcallk` on another Lua function, which just yields. When the yield occurs, execution jumps (longjmp) to the `cont` function, which was provided as an argument to `lua_pcallk`. When the `cont` function returns, the coroutine execution ends and `lua_resume` from the `_tmain` returns.

**An example of `lua_yieldk`:**

```
int cont(lua_State *L)
{
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int yieldktest(lua_State *L)
{
    return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, cont);
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_State *T = lua_newthread(L);

    luaL_loadfile(T, "Test.lua");
    lua_pushcfunction(T, yieldktest);
    lua_resume(T, NULL, 1);
    lua_resume(T, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Lua code:

```
local yieldktest = ...
yieldktest()
```

This bit in turn executes coroutine that yields from within a C function (`yieldktest`). When the coroutine is then resumed (the second `lua_resume`), control is passed back to the continuation function `cont`, which executes as a continuation of `yieldktest`.

These examples do not deal with `lua_getctx` and stack states, but merely demonstrate the mechanisms of those functions.

Comment: `#define luaL_dofile(L, fn) (luaL_loadfile(L, fn) || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))`

I would be curious how `luaL_dofile` fixes the problem?

Comment: @BrandonRos you're asking q question to a thread from 10 years ago. However, from what I remember - exactly as per the include excerpt that you provided, it would execute lua_pcall which the op was missing.